# Action on Google - consume in Transactions forbidden

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-apis-explorer

I follow the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/digital/dev-guide-digital-consumables
Everything works great up to a point when it's time to consume the product.
When calling `https://actions.googleapis.com/v3/conversations/{sessionId}/entitlement:consume`

it returns:

```
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

I tried with the same JWT as I used to make a purchase as well as with a newly generated one. I'm also sure that entitlement.purchaseToken is successfully retrieved.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!
My app is using Service Account key from another project to generate JWT - due to a common app in Google Play Console, which enables me to share purchase entitlements across all my Actions.
As it turned out, this key can not be used in calling consume endpoint: [https://actions.googleapis.com/v3/conversations/${convId}/entitlement:consume](https://actions.googleapis.com/v3/conversations/$%7BconvId%7D/entitlement:consume)
To call it successfully, I have to use Service Account key from the project that the Action belongs to, generate new JWT and the voila! Everything's working as it should.